# is there way to reduce n times nested for-loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 7 iterative parameters: list_1 to list_7
the below code is static and uses 7 for-loops but I have dynamic **n** iterative parameters and need to use **n** for-loop

```
for a in list_1:
    for b in list_2:
        for c in list_3:
            for d in list_4:
                for e in list_5:
                    for f in list_6:
                        for g in list_7:
                            print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Is there any simple solution to solve this problem using pandas or python list or numpy
Note: all list contains string values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`

```
import itertools
all_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5, list_6, list_7]
product = list(itertools.product(all_lists))
```

example to print:

```
for i in itertools.product(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']):
    print(*i)
```

output:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
...
```